# Generate pdf with Bangla language using laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

I am trying to use laravel-dompdf to generate a pdf of a html page which contains Bangla character. But after generating pdf Bangla characters are shown '?' character. please help.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('report.infrastructure', $data);
return $pdf->download('infrastructure.pdf');
```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the [Dompdf Unicode How-To](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo)?

Comment: Add "Kalpurush" or any Unicode font in font list.

Comment: i am facing same problem. Sometimes font are braking and text mismatch . Example Text should be আমি comes out like আ ম ি. can anyone find out this solution?